# Aiming Problems in Modern Combat 5

Tags: technical-issues, modern-combat-5

When I play Modern Combat 5 on my Windows 10 computer, the mouse doesn't match the in-game aim-point. For example, if I move my mouse to the left, the gun moves left, but with the slightest delay. Basically my mouse and the in-game cursor aren't perfectly synced. This greatly affects my precision and accuracy. On my Windows 8 computer, this wasn't a problem, but it may have just been a tweaked computer setting for something. Help?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's your steady aim sensitivity, try reducing lag for your game by putting your TV setting on 'Gamemode'